# ValueError: Not a TBLoader or TBPlugin subclass: <class 'tensorboard_plugin_wit.wit_plugin_loader.WhatIfToolPluginLoader'>

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Tensorboard isn't showing the graphs, failes with following log in jupyter notebook

```
ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 1).
Contents of stderr:

....
raise ValueError("Not a TBLoader or TBPlugin subclass: %s" % plugin)
ValueError: Not a TBLoader or TBPlugin subclass: <class 'tensorboard_plugin_wit.wit_plugin_loader.WhatIfToolPluginLoader'>
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested from @jungin on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/3549#issuecomment-627113695), it worked after uninstalling
tensorboard-plugin-wit

```
pip uninstall tensorboard-plugin-wit --yes
```